# route.post failing to run passport.use

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I'm being thrown a 302 error that I'm struggling to debug on submit, which I'm assuming is missing my passport.use for authentication. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

User.js

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done){
        User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(!user){
                console.log('Unknown User');
                return done(null, false,{message: 'Unknown User'});
            }

      User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
        if (err) throw err;
        if(isMatch){
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          console.log('Invalid password');
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
        }
      });
    });
  }
));

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect: '/users/login',
    failureFlash: 'Invalid Username or Password',
  }),
  // If user authenticates
  function(req, res) {
    console.log('Authentication successful');
    req.flash('success', 'You are logged in');
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Model

```
module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch){
    if(err) return callback(err);
    callback(null, isMatch);
  });
};

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
    User.findById(id, callback);
};

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
    var query = {username: username};
    User.findOne(query, callback);
};
```

Jade

```
extends layout

block content
    h1 Login
    p Please login below
    form(method='post',action='/users/login',enctype='multipart/form-data')
        .form-group
            label Username
            input.form-control(name='username', type='text')
        .form-group
            label Password
            input.form-control(name='password', type='password')
        input.btn.btn-default(name='submit', type='submit',value='Login')
```

As far as I can tell everything should be firing normally. Or can anyone point me in the right direction to debug router.post?

Comment: Update: I've isolated the problem back to passport.authenticate; not sure how to debug from here.

Comment: I am stuck on the same problem. The post route gets never hit in debug. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue wasn't with Express or Passport.
After debugging further, I chased the 'undefined' variables from the form to uncover that the `multipart/form-data'` enctype was to blame.